# Conditional formatting table with R

Tags: r, duplicates, aggregate, apply

I have a table:

```
Time Class  Type Value1 Value2
2005  A      KS    5      6
2005  B      KS    3      3
2005  C      CS    6      6
2006  A      CS    5      3
2006  A      KS    9      2
2006  B      KS    6      9
2006  C      KS   39      6
2007  C      CS   10      20
2007  A      KS   26      23
```

I need to create new data set which contains only rows with the same "Class" and "Type" for each year. For example, for years 2005 and 2006 there are only two rows with the same (common) "Class" and "Type".

Comment: The conditions are not clear especially the `common` Class and Type.  For example `C CS` is common for 2007 and 2005.  But in the output, you removed 2007

Comment: @akrun For each year we should select only rows with the same Type and Class.I edited question. Now output is empty. I added 2007 row to show that your first approach doesn`t work for three years.  Ask more questions if my explanation is unclear.

Comment: But, why did you remove `C CS`.  It is common for two years.  Likewise, `A KS` and `B KS` is not found in 2007.  So, the definition of common is not clear.

Comment: @akrun `C` `CS` must be common for 2005,2006 and 2007

Comment: That is what I was saying.  Based on your logic, `A KS` and `B KS` is only common for 2005 & 2006.

Comment: After the edit, you have only `A KS` that is common for all the years.

Comment: @akrun Finally I edited the table. Now the output must be: `A` `KS`, which is the only common set of Class and Type for three years.

Comment: @akrun Thank you! That works. Could you recommend me the textbook in R?

Comment: Please check this link http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138/resources-for-learning-r  It may be useful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
indx1 <- Reduce(`intersect`,lapply(split(df, df$Time),
      function(x) as.character(interaction(x[,c('Class', 'Type')]))))

df[as.character(interaction(df[,c('Class', 'Type')])) %in% indx1,]
#  Time Class Type Value1 Value2
#1 2005     A   KS      5      6
#5 2006     A   KS      9      2
#9 2007     A   KS     26     23
```

#### data

```
  df <- structure(list(Time = c(2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 
  2006L, 2007L, 2007L), Class = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", 
  "C", "C", "A"), Type = c("KS", "KS", "CS", "CS", "KS", "KS", 
  "KS", "CS", "KS"), Value1 = c(5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 39L, 10L, 
  26L), Value2 = c(6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 6L, 20L, 23L)), .Names = c("Time", 
  "Class", "Type", "Value1", "Value2"), class = "data.frame", row.names =
  c(NA, -9L))
```